# Terraform AWS: Unable to copy file into EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I am new to terraform. I have a Dockerized application that can be deployed using a docker-compose file.

I wrote a terraform script that creates a a security group, an EC2 machine, and runs a script that downloads docker and docker-compose, and I am trying to upload this docker-compose file from the local machine to the remote one. Whenever terraform reaches this step, it generates the following error:

```
aws_instance.docker_swarm: Provisioning with 'file'... 
Error: host for provisioner cannot be empty
```

Below is the terraform template:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 2.70"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  profile = var.profile
  region  = var.region
}

resource "aws_security_group" "allow_ssh_http" {
  name        = "allow_ssh_http"
  description = "Allow SSH and HTTP access to ports 22 and 1337"

  ingress {
    description = "SSH from everywhere"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    description = "Access Port 1337 from Everywhere"
    from_port   = 1337
    to_port     = 1337
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "allow_ssh_http"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "docker_swarm" {
  ami           = var.amis[var.region]
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  key_name = var.key_name
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.allow_ssh_http.id]

    user_data = "${file("deployServices.sh")}"

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "./docker-compose.yml"
    destination = "/home/ubuntu/docker-compose.yml"
  }
    tags = {
        Name = "NK Microservices Stack" 
    }
}

output "ec2_id" {
  value = aws_instance.docker_swarm.id
}

output "ec2_ip" {
  value = aws_instance.docker_swarm.public_ip
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need to provide [connection](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/connection.html) details to the `provisioner`. For example:

```
resource "aws_instance" "docker_swarm" {
  ami           = var.amis[var.region]
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  key_name = var.key_name
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.allow_ssh_http.id]

  user_data = "${file("deployServices.sh")}"

  provisioner "file" {

    source      = "./docker-compose.yml"
    destination = "/home/ubuntu/docker-compose.yml"

    connection {   
      host        = self.public_ip
      user        = "ubuntu"
      private_key = file("<path-to-private-ssh-key>")
    }   

  }

  tags = {
     Name = "NK Microservices Stack" 
  }
}
```

where `<path-to-private-ssh-key>` is the ssh key associated with your `var.key_name`.

Comment: I need to have the file on the machine before running the user data. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @NicolasElKhoury You could add some wait loop in your user-data script , which checks for the existance of the file. If the file does not exist, wait loop will sleep for few seconds and try again, until the file is found.

Comment: @NicolasElKhoury How did it go?

Answer (score 0):

The Terraform documentation states that you should only use provisioners as a last resort.

User Data can contain [files](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html) in addition to a startup script. I would definitely recommend that approach before trying to use a provisioner. Or you could even include the file as a [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) in the user data script.

Alternatively, you could copy the file to S3 before running Terraform, or even use Terraform to [upload the file to S3](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_object), and then simply have the EC2 instance download the file as part of the user data script.